# javascript jquery create and listen for event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, triggers, listen

Is there an simple example of how to create an event in javascript and listen for it?

Trying to create a Complete event, similar to the ajaxComplete. Want other stuff on the page to show messages when Complete event is fired.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/ and http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: Don't use bind - use `on` (or delegate for older jQuery versions)

Answer (score 3):

```
//create a hanlder:
$('.myselector, .myDue').on('myEvent',function(){
  alert('custom event fired');
});

//trigger the event a few ways:
$('.myselector').trigger('myEvent');

$('.myselector').click(function(){
    $(this).trigger('myEvent');
});

function hitTheTrigger(whatwashit){
   $(whatwashit).trigger('myEvent');
}

hitTheTrigger('.myDue');
hitTheTrigger('.myselector');
```

test it out here:http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/rTNTg/

Comment: +1 but I think you meant  `$(document).on('myEvent', '.myselector, .myDue', function(){`

Comment: Getting error wiht answer and comment. ".on" is not a function and the answer above said it was missing an ")" something about the argument list.

Comment: oops, there was a syntax error of . instead of , in the event handler. NOTE: uses jQuery